# Batch Counter not working

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I've got this code on a batch file:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (kim.txt) do (
    set /a var+=1
    echo Line %var%
)
```

But %var% don't seem to increment, it's always at zero. Tried different aproaches without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under delayed expansion you need to access your variables (in case their value changes within brackets context) with `!` instead of `%` :

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (kim.txt) do (
    set /a var+=1
    echo Line !var!
)
```

Comment: Yes, `%` variables are expanded when the _command_ is read. The command in this instance is the entire four-line `for` statement. `!` vars are how you get the delayed expansion, because they're expanded when the _lines_ are interpreted.